# How to find which class object is sitting on a particular index of an array (Polymorphism )

Tags: c++

I have a base class of Bank that is being inherited by classes "Saving", "Checking", "Current" and "Investment". I am practicing polymorphism for my school.

I have a code that that is pretty long that I can't share here. All I am doing here in this piece of code is allocating dynamic array(that I have separate function for, grow2D) at pointer this->bank and creating objects on the runtime by asking the user if he wants to create an object of "Saving", "Checking", "Current" or "Investment" account. my question is that, after I am done creating the objects by asking the user, how can I check which type("Saving", "Checking", "Current" or "Investment") of object is sitting on a particular index.

For instance the use creates an object of type "Savings" at bank[0]. How can I find what type of object is sitting on bank[0] later in my code when user is done adding all the accounts?

```
    string name;
    unsigned long long int accountNumber;
    unsigned long int balance;
    int option = 0;
    size++;
    this->bank = grow2D(bank, size);
    cout <<endl << "1 for Saving" << endl;
    cout << "2 for Checking" << endl;
    cout << "3 for Current" << endl;
    cout << "4 for Investment" << endl;
    cout << "Enter option";
    cin >> option;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter name";
    getline(cin, name);

    cout << "Enter Account Number";
    cin >> accountNumber;
    cout << "Enter Balance";
    cin >> balance;
    if(option==1)
    {
        int interestRate;
        cout << "Enter Interest Rate: ";
        cin >> interestRate;
        bank[size - 1] = new Saving(name,accountNumber,balance,interestRate);
    }
    else if (option == 2)
    {
        int fee;
        cout << "Enter Fee: ";
        cin >> fee;
        bank[size - 1] = new Checking(name, accountNumber, balance,fee);
    }
    else if (option == 3)
    {
        int fee;
        unsigned long int minimumBalance;
        cout << "Enter Fee: ";
        cin >> fee;
        cout << "Enter Minimum balance: ";
        cin >> minimumBalance;
        bank[size - 1] = new Current(name, accountNumber, balance,fee,minimumBalance);
    }
    else if (option == 4)
    {
        int fee;
        unsigned long int minimumBalance;
        int profit;
        cout << "Enter Fee: ";
        cin >> fee;
        cout << "Enter Minimum balance: ";
        cin >> minimumBalance;
        cout << "Enter Profit: ";
        cin >> profit;
        bank[size - 1] = new Investment(name, accountNumber, balance, fee, minimumBalance,profit);
    }
```

Comment: The point of polymorphism is that it doesn't matter what the actual type is. Your design may need some work. This is a pretty common issue in C++ where people want all the benefits of polymorphism + all the benefits of separate types. It's called the *expression problem* and there are some ways around it, but probably nothing that you should be using in this assignment.

Comment: because I am just a second semester student, I am not sure of a lot of work arounds.

Comment: you shouldn't "workaround", you shouldnt need to know what is the actual type. Please try to create a [mcve]. We need not see all of your code, but the definition of the base and the deriveds are needed to suggest a fix

Comment: You can add a function to the parent class called `getType`, which returns the type of the object.

Comment: @SanaYounas *how can I check which type("Saving", "Checking", "Current" or "Investment") of object is sitting on a particular index.* -- Then the questions to you are -- Why do you need to check?  What is the "checking" code supposed to accomplish in general?  As the first comment suggested, you are defeating the entire purpose of polymorphism if you have batches of code that does something custom depending on the type, thus the constant need to check.  Code littered with "if type is A do this, if it's B do that, if it's C do something else" should be avoided.

Comment: @ChrisMM what would the implementation look like? I mean how would I compare if index 0 is of "Savings" type?

Comment: Note that the `if` checks would be necessary to determine what type of object to create.  But after that, be very wary of doing the `if` checks beyond object creation, because each time you do this, you are breaking what polymorphism is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: can you explain why you think you need to know what is the type of the objects? Then maybe we can explain you why you don't need to know it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your classes contain at least one virtual method (at least the destructor should be virtual), e.g.:

```
class Saving {
public:
    virtual ~Saving() = default;
};

class Checking: public Saving {};
class Current: public Saving {};
class Investment: public Saving {};
```

Then you can use [`typeid()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) to query the runtime-type of the object.
Example:

```cpp
#include <typeinfo>

Saving* s = new Current();

if(typeid(*s) == typeid(Current)) {
  std::cout << "It's a Current!" << std::endl;
}

if(typeid(*s) == typeid(Investment)) {
  std::cout << "It's an Investment!" << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively you can also use [`dynamic_cast()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) and check if the cast was successful to the derived type:

```cpp
Saving* s = new Investment();

Investment* investment = dynamic_cast<Investment*>(s);
if(investment != nullptr) {
  std::cout << "It's an Investment!" << std::endl;
}

Current* current = dynamic_cast<Current*>(s);
if(current != nullptr) {
  std::cout << "It's a Current!" << std::endl;
}

// etc...
```

Comment: Lets say I have a double pointer array Bank** bank= new Bank*[size]; so in the "typeid example" (typeid(*s) == typeid(Current)) should I write if(typeid(this->bank[i]== typeid(Current))?

Comment: I suggest forget about the `typeid`.  It is not guaranteed to work as you expect if you read the Notes section.